# How can I add a Font Awesome icon to this code blogger template code

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I tried adding a **FontAwesome** icon to my code but the icon isn't showing when I preview my website.

I added the icon with this code.

```
<b:widget-setting name='text-1'><i class='fa fa-info-circle'/>Demo</b:widget-setting>
```

I also tried;

```
<b:widget-setting name='text-1'> <i class='fa fa-info-circle'>Demo</i></b:widget-setting>
```

But the icon does not show.
Please note that this code is for a blogger template and I add the menu through the LAYOUT option.

**Here is the complete code:**

```
<b:section class='layikiMenu' id='layikiMenu' maxwidgets='1' name='Main Menu' showaddelement='no'>
 <b:widget id='LinkList56' locked='true' title='Main Menu' type='LinkList' version='2' visible='true'>

            <b:widget-settings>
              <b:widget-setting name='link-3'>https://google.com/</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>NONE</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='text-1'>Demo</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='link-1'>https://google.com/</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='text-0'>Home</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='link-2'>https://google.com</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='text-3'>Donate</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='link-0'>/</b:widget-setting>
              <b:widget-setting name='text-2'>Hello</b:widget-setting>
            </b:widget-settings>
            <b:includable id='main'>
              <b:include name='content'/>
            </b:includable>
            <b:includable id='content'>
              <ul id='layiki-list' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement' role='navigation'>
                <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
                  <li itemprop='name'><a expr:href='data:link.target' itemprop='url' target='_blank'><data:link.name/></a></li>
                </b:loop>
              </ul>
            </b:includable>
          </b:widget>
        </b:section>  `
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you maybe show us your entire code (including the head)?

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, you must register for a free account at https://fontawesome.com/. Then, go to https://fontawesome.com/account/cdn and copy the code it gives you, and stick it in your `<head>`
tags. That should make it work.

Comment: Okay, I will try that right away. Thanks.

Comment: I will do that.

Comment: can you show us your head, maybe you just did it wrong?

Comment: <head>
    
    <script crossorigin='anonymous' src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/6efac77791.js'/>
 <!--- Blogger Template /-->
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
    <title><data:view.title.escaped/></title>
      <meta expr:content='&quot;text/html; charset=&quot; + data:blog.encoding' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>

Comment: Include `https://` in front of `kit.fontawesome[...]`. If you don't do that, the link will lead to `https://yoursitename.tld/kit.fontawesome[...]`.